# Which is the limit of the sequence $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\cos(i^2)}{n^2+i^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I can't find the limit as n $\to$ infinity of the sequence:

$$\frac{\cos(1)}{n^2 + 1} + \frac{\cos(4)}{n^2 + 4} + \dots + \frac{\cos(n^2)}{n^2 + n^2}$$

I tried to use the inequality $\cos(n^2) < n$ which I could justify it by using Taylor series of $\cos x$ and replacing the $x$ with $x^2$ but my professor told me I was wrong.Plus I plotted $\cos(x^2)$ and $x$ and I saw that he was right. So I don't have any ideas left and I need some help here. Even though this is an exercise that my professor gave me it is not an exercise for the semester or anything like that it's more like exercise that he gave me for fun. (I asked for it.I should have been more careful :) )

Comment: Is it $\frac{\cos(1)}{n^2+1}$ or is it $\cos\left(\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)$?

Comment: Originally the last term was phrased as "cos(n\^{}2)/((n\^{}2) + (n\^{}2))".

Comment: @5xum It is the first one that you wrote.

Comment: A more interesting challenge is to prove: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(k)}{n+k}=0,$$ too.

Comment: I will try to solve it and I will post my findings if there will be any. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\cos(i^2)}{n^2+i^2}$$ is in modulus less than or equal to

$$\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\vert \cos(i^2) \right\vert \right] \big/ n^2$$

The numerator is less than or equal to $n$.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos x \approx 1- \frac{x^2}{2}$ for small values of $x$. For large values of $x$ (which you need to study, since your limit is $n\to\infty$), the approximation does not hold.

To actually calculate the sum, you can notice that each element in the sum is smaller than $\frac{1}{n^2}$, and there are only $n$ elements which you sum, therefore their sum is smaller than $\frac n{n^2}=\frac1n$

Comment: I know it's against the rules, but thanks to both of you for your valuable help.

Comment: @underdog012 Thanking a post you did not accept is not against the rules, because your thanks is informative (to anyone reading this question in a month, he will know that both answers were useful to you).'

Comment: @underdog012 it's even legal to upvote both answers :-)

Comment: @robjohn Yes I know. That's what I did. :) It says with faded grayish letters in the comment box to avoid comments like "+1" or "Thanks" that is why I said that it might be against the rules.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\cos 1}{n^2 + 1}+ \frac{\cos 4}{n^2 + 4}+ \dots + \frac{\cos n^2}{n^2 + n^2}\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{\cos 1}{n^2}}{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}+ \frac{\frac{\cos 4}{n^2}}{1 + \frac{4}{n^2}}+ \dots + \frac{\frac{\cos n^2}{n^2}}{1 + 1}\right)$$
Since the limit of each term as $n\to \infty$ yields a convergent limit, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\cos 1}{n^2}}{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\cos 4}{n^2}}{1 + \frac{4}{n^2}}+ \dots + \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\cos n^2}{n^2}}{1 + 1}$$
$$=\frac{0}{1 + 0}+\frac{0}{1 + 0}+ \dots + \frac{0}{1+1}=0$$